# Find More than 1 Line of Text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

There is an Question and four options then there is `<----->` to indicate the end of question. I want to check if certain question contain in the document of 1 Million Lines. So Instead of Finding them one by one. I want to bulk search them.
The breaking of one phosphate bond from ATP releases energy:
Who discovered the details of dark reactions?
How can I find only these lines in the entire document?

```
The breaking of one phosphate bond from ATP releases energy:
7.3 Kcal
7.9 Kcal
7.5 Kcal
7.1 Kcal
<----->
Loss of electron is called:
Oxidation
Reduction
Redox Reaction
Oxidation and reduction reaction
<----->
Who discovered the details of dark reactions?
Malvin Calvin
Schwan
Schleiden
Robert Brown
<----->
```

Comment: Your questio is not very clear, what are the rules to select lines? And what lines?

Comment: Well There is an Question and four options then there is `<----->` to indicate the end of question. I want to check if certain question contain in the document of 1 Million Lines.
So Instead of Finding them one by one. I want to bulk search them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:The breaking of one phosphate bond from ATP releases energy:|Who discovered the details of dark reactions\?).+?<----->`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:     # non capture group, matches literally
    The breaking of one phosphate bond from ATP releases energy:
|       # OR
    Who discovered the details of dark reactions\?
)       # end group
.+?     # 1 or more any character, not greedy
<-----> # literally
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]